# ksh regex error '=~` unexpected

Tags: regex, ksh, aix

I have a rpm spec that runs some tests in the %pre section.

I am using AIX 5.3 and the korn shell.

my script greps something out of ps i.e foo and foobar (I only want foo) and then tests each value to see if it matches a pattern.

However the code

```
if [[ $x =~ foo$ ]]; then echo match fi
```

returns the error **=~ unexpected**

man says string =~ ere

True if string  matches the pattern ~(E)ere  where ere  is an extended regular expression.

So it seems that =~ is supported.

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why not have `grep` apply the regex for you, rather than postprocessing? (If I knew your platform better, I'd suggest using tools better suited to the task than grepping output of `ps` at all -- pgrep and kin are more likely to be the Right Thing on Linux, but I don't have an AIX system at hand to inspect/test against).

Comment: thanks. I may indeed try this since ultimately I would like my script to work across both AIX/Linux KSH88/Bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex for what you're doing (checking whether a string has a given suffix) at all.

```
if [[ $x = *foo ]]; then echo match; fi
```

...provides equivalent behavior to

```
if [[ $x =~ foo$ ]]; then echo match; fi
```

...but, of course, works on shells without the latter feature.

---

If you *do* want to use `=~` inside of `[[ ]]`, then make sure you're running ksh93; the default ksh on AIX is a much older implementation.

To run ksh93, start your script with `#!/usr/bin/ksh93`, not `#!/usr/bin/ksh`.

Comment: How would you use this when the string you're trying to match has a leading space  
`[[ $x = * foo ]]` doesn't seem to work, the leading space causes a syntax error because * was not expected

Comment: @Nicolasome, `[[ $x = *" "foo ]]` is fine. It's not about the `*` being unexpected, it's about `=` only expecting one word on its right-hand side, and requiring quoting or escaping to ensure that the RHS content parses as one word.

Comment: @Nicolasome, ...btw, you can always set `var='* foo'` and then check whether `[[ $x = $var ]]`; when used exactly that way, it'll still treat the `*` as a wildcard (whereas if you added quotes, and made it `[[ $x = "$var" ]]`, then it would treat the `*` as an exact string to match against).